# Node & MongoDB - TypeError: Cannot set property 'userProfileModel' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am getting this error while trying to do a logon test in Postman. I already did a register test and all the input fields were registered with a 200 Status and made sure all the entries are posted using Robomongo. But when I try to do a logon with `userName` and `password`, this is where I get the following TypeError:

```
(node:13962) DeprecationWarning: crypto.pbkdf2 without specifying a digest is deprecated. Please specify a digest
/Users/Wilo/Desktop/myway_stuff/myway_app/MyWay/server/controllers/account.js:63
                    me.account.userProfileModel = userProfileModel;
                                                ^

TypeError: Cannot set property 'userProfileModel' of undefined
    at InternalFieldObject.ondone (/Users/Wilo/Desktop/myway_stuff/myway_app/MyWay/server/controllers/account.js:63:49)
```

Here is a snippet where the logon function is executed within my `account.js` controller:

AccountController.prototype.logon = function(userName, password, callback) {

```
var me = this;

me.userModel.findOne({ userName: userName }, function (err, user) {

    if (err) {
        return callback(err, new me.ApiResponse({ success: false, extras: { msg: me.ApiMessages.DB_ERROR } }));
    }

    if (user && user.passwordSalt) {

        me.hashPassword(password, user.passwordSalt, function (err, passwordHash) {

            if (passwordHash == user.passwordHash) {

                var userProfileModel = new me.UserProfile({
                    userName: user.userName,
                    email: user.email,
                    firstName: user.firstName,
                    lastName: user.lastName
                });

                //Save to HTTP account
                me.account.userProfileModel = userProfileModel; // This is Line 63 in the stacktrace
                me.account.id = me.uuid.v4();

                //Save to persistent account
                me.userAccount.userId = user._id;
                me.userAccount.accountId = me.account.id;

                me.userAccount.save(function (err, accountData, numberAffected) {

                    if (err) {
                        return callback(err, new me.ApiResponse({ success: false, extras: { msg: me.ApiMessages.DB_ERROR } }));
                    }

                    if (numberAffected === 1) {
                        // Return the user profile so the router sends it to the client app doing the logon.
                        return callback(err, new me.ApiResponse({
                            success: true, extras: {
                                userProfileModel: userProfileModel,
                                accountId: me.account.id
                            }
                        }));                            
                    } else {

                        return callback(err, new me.ApiResponse({ success: false, extras: { msg: me.ApiMessages.COULD_NOT_CREATE_ACCOUNT } }));
                    }
                });                    
            } else {
                return callback(err, new me.ApiResponse({ success: false, extras: { msg: me.ApiMessages.INVALID_PWD } }));
            }
        });
    } else {
        return callback(err, new me.ApiResponse({ success: false, extras: { msg: me.ApiMessages.EMAIL_NOT_FOUND } }));
    }

});
```

};

Would appreciate any help regarding this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you "me" variable does not have account variable/parameter.